# Cannot access a file in the theme (twentynineteen-child) folder

Tags: forms

Get a 403 Forbidden Error on the Server when I try to access this script which processes form data. Works on my Local Machine though.
http://example.com/wp-content/themes/twentynineteen-child/add_restaurant.php

Here's my form action.

```
<form action="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri()  . "/add_restaurant.php"; ?>" id="add_restaurant" method="post">
```

Comment: Thanks for the Negative Point. Was extremely frustrated after doing a lot of research. That's why I asked the question here.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your code... its better way to help you.

So, I guess you have html form ?

An idea :

Don't specify any path on your form and let manage it into your functions.php

```
add_action('init', 'my_form_process');
function my_form_process(){
  // Do nonce check, Post check...
}
```

Have look for Nonce security check : [Nonce WordPress page](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces)